# How to set CursorLine highlight color for the gruvbox colorscheme

Tags: colorscheme, highlight, color, cursorline

When I use the colorscheme [gruvbox](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox) (installed with [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)), it overrides my configuration of the Cursorline highlight, eg

```
set cursorline
hi CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=black
```

with the same color as the statusbar, which makes it easy to confuse the cursorline with the statusline of a horizontally split buffer.

I would like to set the cursorline background color to pure black, or at least to the black defined by the gruvbox colorscheme, but I can't change the highlight using the `hi(ghlight) CursorLine` command when using gruvbox.

I couldn't find how to configure this in the [gruvbox wiki](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/wiki/Configuration), does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: Also: [How to customize colorschemes without editing their source files?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24846/18609)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearently this line

```
set termguicolors
```

overrides the highlight color. 
removing it let me configure the CursorLine highlight color again.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me, in your `.vimrc` first set your colorscheme, then your desired highlight:

```
colorscheme gruvbox
highlight Cursorline whatever_you_like
```

That way your colorscheme won't clobber your highlight.

Comment: yes, that is what I use now too. The problem was `set termguicolors`